# How can Terminal Velocity be greater than gravity?

Tags: gravity, velocity

It's been over a decade since my last high school physics class, so I apologize in advance if this is a dumb/ignorant question, but how can a skydiver fall faster than the speed of gravity? If gravity is a constant and equates to a little less than 22mph, then how can high altitude skydivers reach speed of over 800 MPH (e.g. Felix Baumgartner)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Gravity isn't a constant, and it certainly isn't a velocity.

Comment: The [speed of gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_gravity) is 299,792,458 meters per second, but I'm pretty sure that's not what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you're talking about Earth where the average acceleration due to gravity is about $g=9.8m/s^2$. There is simply no 'speed' of gravity. This is simply an acceleration, not a speed. Terminal velocity occurs (from henceforth, I'll be using classical mechanics without relativity since it's unencessary) when the force of drag due to air resistance is equivalent to the force of gravity. This leaves a net force (and thus a net acceleration) of $0$.

$\sum F=ma$

Terminal velocity is defined as the following:
$$
V_t= \sqrt{\frac{2mg}{\rho Ak_d }}
$$
Where:
$
m = \text{mass}\\
g = \text{acceleration due to gravity}\\
\rho =mv= \text{momentum (mass x velocity)}\\
A = \text{projected area (essentiall the downward facing surface area)}\\
k_d = \text{drag coefficient}
\\$

When the force due to air resistence subtracted from the force of gravity results in zero, you've reached terminal velocity. This is the famous Drag Equation:
$$F_{net} = m a = m g - {1 \over 2} \rho v^2 A C_\mathrm{d}$$

The way skydivers can fall at different velocities is by changing any one of those constants. They cannot change their mass or the gravity of Earth, but they can change the projected area. For example, outstretched hands with your face looking downward will have significantly more projected area then the diving position with the top of your head pointed at the ground.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Isn't $\rho$ the density of the air? This is considerably less at high altitude than close to the surface of the Earth, so terminal velocity can be greater at high altitude.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "speed of gravity".  You might be referring to acceleration due to gravity:  gravity speeds up a falling object.  However, that acceleration is strictly applicable only if there are no other forces.  Air drag is another force.  It causes the acceleration of the object to reach zero at the object's terminal velocity.